# Regex to match URL's except the src attributes of image tags

Tags: php, regex

So i have a regex that matches urls.

```
$pat = '/((?:https?|ftp):\/\/\S+)/u';
```

However, my ***img tags*** also include urls.

```
<img class="summernote-image" src="http://random.jp/~name/files/Pikachu.jpg">
```

How can I match all urls without matching the ones inside an image tag using a regex (or any other way)?

Comment: Which language or flavour of regex you're using ?

Comment: I am using PHP.

Answer (score 3):

***Since you didn't updated flavour of language you're using.***

So i can't tell you the language specific answer.

> But a generic one will be all you need is to use `negative look behind`.

Something like this.

```
(?<!src="|href=")(?:https?|ftp):\/\/\S+
```

- `(?<!src="|href=")` - Negative look behind this means match thing which is not preceded by `src="` or `href="`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nNlOXA/2)

Thanks to **@certainoerformance** for valuable input :)

Comment: I think it's generally a good idea to use capturing groups only when you need to use the captured text later - non-capturing groups should probably be used by default, it makes the code's intent a bit clearer when you can effectively say through your code "I'm using a group for the sake of pattern logic only" (and not because the text the group contains will matter later)

Comment: In this case, I think you can feel free to remove *all* of the capturing groups completely (not just replace with non-capturing, but remove entirely, I don't think they're doing anything)

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for your valuable input. updated my answer :)